# How can i turn this "half pole" into a perfect cylinder

Tags: modeling

Im trying to make this type of lightpole

[image: lightpole]

but i cant figure out on how i can turn this into a nice and round cylinder.
I can of course do it manually but it looks bad so is there any modifiers etc i cant use?

[image: bad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a torus, remove 3/4:

[image]

Cut off its half:

[image]

Fill:

[image]

Extrude horizontally and vertically, mirror (don't keep the inner face along the axis):

[image]